# Making a Flat file database

Tags: vb.net, text

I am trying to make a flat file database for my VB.NET application,and as it is a small school project i don't need MySQL database. I am programming in visual basic and i am wondering how i could save user information(username,password) in a text file, separate it by tab and then read it when logging in. 
Basically a login/registration system using a flat file database. Does anyone have any suggestions on where to start and how to separate data by tab and even ignore tabs when reading data?

Thanks very much , in advance.

Comment: Why separate by tabs? Have a look at _[Binary Serialization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254617/Serialization-Part-I-Binary-Serialization)_ instead. It is much more efficient as you get to use classes with properties/fields which will give you a better data structure.

Comment: Thank you, I will.

Answer (score 0):

This should be of use to you.

Reading the data:

```
Dim ofd1 As New OpenFileDialog
if ofd1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK then

Dim reader As New StreamReader(ofd1.FileName)
Do While reader.Peek() >= 0
Dim curline As String = reader.ReadLine()
Dim vals() As String = curline.Split(vbTab)
    Dim username as string = vals(0)
    Dim password as string = vals(1)

    MessageBox.Show("username: " & username)
    MessageBox.Show("password: " & password)

        Loop
        reader.Close()
  end if
```

file.txt

```
username1(tab)password1
username2(tab)password2
```

Comment: **First, _and most important_ of all**, you **must** check if `ofd1.ShowDialog()` evaluates to `DialogResult.OK`. That means that the user have selected a file and pressed to open it. If you don't do it you will run into trouble if the user decides to cancel the opening. --- This can be done via a simple `If`-statement: `If ofd1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then`.

Comment: Secondly, while `Not curline Is Nothing` (or `curline IsNot Nothing`) does work for checking when there's nothing more to read, I'd rather recommend looping by `Not reader.EndOfStream` instead. The `EndOfStream` property will tell you when the stream has reached it's end, i.e. when there's nothing more to read from the file.

Comment: I love the split method. Back when i didn't fully understand all of the techniques i do now, i used {{!!IfAnybodyIncludesThisExactTextInOneOfTheirEntriesIWillF**KINGCUTYOU!!}} as a separator when making applications for the company to use.